# Django Javascript: How To Use Class Name With Template Tag Inside As Identifier in Function

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am using a for loop to print out all of the posts on my site and each post will have a form that allows users to add that post to a list. I am trying to use ajax to do this so that there is no page refresh. The ajax function works on the first post but on all of the others there are issues. i think that the issues are due to each post having the same class name that is being used to identify it, so this is why i want to use the forloop counter in the class name so that each one has a unique identifier.

EDIT:The issues are that the buttons on each form should change class and text, which works on the first post, but on most of the posts this doesn't work.

Here is some relevant code:

Javascript:

```
#this is where i want the class to have a tag inside

$('.collection_save_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const url = $(this).attr('action')
        const post_id = $(this).attr('name')
        const collection_id = $(this).attr('id')
        const text = $(`.saved_text${collection_id}`).text()
        var saveElement = document.getElementById(`save_btn${collection_id}`);


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                'post_id': post_id,
                'collection_id': collection_id,


            },
            success: function(response){
                if (saveElement.classList.contains("saved")){
                
                    saveElement.classList.remove("saved")
                    $(`.saved_text${collection_id}`).text('Save')

                } else if (!$(this).hasClass("saved")) {
                    
                    saveElement.classList.add("saved")
                    $(`.saved_text${collection_id}`).text('Saved')
                }

            
                
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log('error', response)
            }
        })

    })
```

Code with the form:

```
{% for item in posts %}

    #irrelevant post data

    {% for collection in collections %}
        <div class="collection_save_container">
        <div class="collection_save_name">{{ collection.collection_name }}</div>
        {% if item.post in collection.posts.all %}

            #here the class of the form should have a class that ends with something like {{ item.id }}
            <form class="collection_save_form" action="{% url 'savepost' item.post.id collection.id %}" method="POST" id="{{ collection.id }}" name="{{ item.post.id }}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="collection_save_btn saved" id="save_btn{{ collection.id }}"><div class="saved_text{{ collection.id }}">Saved</div></button>
            </form>
        {% else %}

            #here the class of the form should have a class that ends with something like {{ item.id}} }}
            <form class="collection_save_form" action="{% url 'savepost' item.post.id collection.id %}" method="POST" id="{{ collection.id }}" name="{{ item.post.id }}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="collection_save_btn" id="save_btn{{ collection.id }}"><div class="saved_text{{ collection.id }}">Save</div></button>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: cann you please elaborate in more details about ```[..] there are issues```  what kind of issues??

Comment: The classes on the buttons don't change like the ajax code should be making it do, but it is working on the first post so thats why i think there is an issue that it doesn't know which form to use and thats why i need to find a way to identify each one like putting an id in the class name or something else

Comment: Ok so you have a hypothesis, have you confirm or denied it then by checking what happens in your JS? like that everytime you click on the button of a new form the actual correct form triggers the event?

Comment: i have tried commenting out the javascript and the form works and the classes change as the page refreshes. So the issue is to do with the javascript. the form does trigger the event and so the post is added to the list, but the buttons have issues where the right class isn't being put on or it is being put on when it hasn't even been clicked yet.

Comment: I think the problem is about making ajax call. Elements in template are not rerendered without page refresh. It seems you have to refresh or handle changing class names via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so im answering my own question for anyone who ever has a similar problem

The save element is refering to id `save_btn${collection_id}`

```
var saveElement = document.getElementById(`save_btn${collection_id}`);
```

but there is no way to identify which post on the parent loop that this is from so it needs to be

```
var saveElement = document.getElementById(`save_btn${collection_id}${post_id}`);
```